# Processing standard audio output

Tags: audio, processing, minim

Is it possible to, with the use of Processing and Minim (or other libraries / languages), create an [AudioInput](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/javadoc/ddf/minim/AudioInput.html) like object to monitor any and all audio output?

For example I am working on a visualizer of sorts, but would like to allow another application to be playing the music rather than using the Playback class or something of the like.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, you can use Soundflower to redirect audio through virtual drivers. Otherwise look into JACK Audio

Comment: Yeah I've been using this for the time being, but was just wondering if there was a built-in fix for this as well.